# How do I match on the concrete type of a generic parameter?

Tags: types, rust, match

I have a function with a type parameter `U` that returns an `Option<U>`. `U` is bound by the trait `num::Num`. As such, `U` can be a `usize`, `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64`, `u128`, `isize`, etc.

How do I match `U`? E.g.,

```
match U {
    u8 => {},
    u16 => {}
    _ => {}
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume the reason you'd like to match against a type is because you'd like to have the *switching* at compile time instead of runtime.  Unfortunately Rust does not have that kind of inspection (yet?), but what you could do is create a trait for this which then you can implement for the types you'd like to use:

```
trait DoSomething {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Option<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized;
}

impl DoSomething for u8 {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Option<u8> {
        Some(8)
    }
}

impl DoSomething for u16 {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Option<u16> {
        Some(16)
    }
}

fn f<U>(x: U) -> Option<U>
where
    U: DoSomething,
{
    x.do_something()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", f(12u8));
    println!("{:?}", f(12u16));
}
```

Comment: Beautiful; thank you!

Comment: No worries, I'm glad if I could help!

Comment: On an extended note for later consideration: The rust team really should add directly matching type-parameters to primitives'/structs without the added loop of implementations. Where art thou, Rust-Lang Team?

Comment: @ThomasBraun well, you could achieve something similar with [proc-macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html), are you familiar with those?  Since you are working at the AST level, you could match against the types there.

Comment: Although, the two would have different effects: if your `do_something` is complex and long and it is very different from type to type, and invoked more than once, it is better to have them as functions in the `impl` blocks over inserting the same function bodies over and over again for example.